# TinyMCE Enable button while in read only mode

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have a TinyMCE 4.x instance where the text should be in read only mode. But I still have some buttons that I want to have enabled. For example, one button could provide a character count for the part of the text I've selected.
But when I turn on read only mode for TinyMCE all buttons are disabled. Can I enable just my buttons while still retaining read only mode?

Comment: Have you found a solution?
I am also looking for this.

Comment: Nope, not yet. But I haven't really had time to dig into it anymore. I've had more pressing matters.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably too late for you but other people may pass by here.

I came up by writing this function

```
function enableTinyMceEditorPlugin(editorId, pluginName, commandName) {
    var htmlEditorDiv = document.getElementById(editorId).previousSibling;
    var editor = tinymce.get(editorId);
    var buttonDiv = htmlEditorDiv.querySelectorAll('.mce-i-' + pluginName.toLowerCase())[0].parentElement.parentElement;
    buttonDiv.className = buttonDiv.className.replace(' mce-disabled', '');
    buttonDiv.removeAttribute('aria-disabled');
    buttonDiv.firstChild.onclick = function () {
        editor.execCommand(commandName);
    };
}
```

It does the trick in 2 steps:

- make the button clickable (remove `mce-disabled` CSS class and remove the `aria-disabled` property)
- assign the good command to the click event

And in my editor `init` event I call the function.

```
editor.on('init', function () {
    if (readOnly) {
        editor.setMode('readonly');
        enableTinyMceEditorPlugin(htmlEditorId, 'preview', 'mcePreview');
        enableTinyMceEditorPlugin(htmlEditorId, 'code', 'mceCodeEditor');
    }
});
```

Current version of TinyMCE for which I wrote this code is 4.4.3. It may break in a future version, specifically about the selectors to get and modify the good HTML elements.

Command identifiers can be found at [this page](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/editor-command-identifiers) otherwise you can also find them under `tinymce\plugins\PluginName\plugin(.min).js`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to enable your custom toolbar button and attach a click event handler inside a read only TinyMCE editor using JQUERY:

```
//Initialize read only Tinymce editor so that Lock button is also disabled
function initReadOnlyTinyMCE() {
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#main'
        , toolbar: 'myLockButton'
        , body_class: 'main-div'
        , content_css: 'stylesheets/index.css'
        , readonly: true
        , setup: function (readOnlyMain) {
            readOnlyMain.addButton('myLockButton', { //Lock button is disabled because readonly is set to true
                image: 'images/lock.png'
                , tooltip: 'Lock Editor'
            });
        }
    });
}

function displayReadOnlyTinyMCEwithLockButtonEnabled() {
    var edContent = $('main').html();
    $("#main").empty();
    initReadOnlyTinyMCE(true);
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(edContent);
    //enable the lock button and attach a click event handler
    $('[aria-label="Lock Editor"]').removeClass("mce-disabled");
    $('[aria-label="Lock Editor"]').removeAttr("aria-disabled");
    $('[aria-label="Lock Editor"]').attr("onclick", "LockEditor()");
}

function LockEditor() {
    alert("Tiny mce editor is locked by the current user!!");
    //Write your logic to lock the editor...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an easy way to do this. The simplest way is to remove the contenteditable attribute from the iframe body instead and substitute a read only toolbar set. It also means that people will still be able to copy content from the editor.

```
$("iframe").contents().find("body").removeAttr("contenteditable");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
editor.addButton('yourButton', {
        title: 'One can Enable/disable TinyMCE',
        text: "Disable",
        onclick: function (ee) {
            editor.setMode('readonly');
            if($(ee.target).text() == "Disable"){
                var theEle = $(ee.target).toggle();
                var edit = editor;
                var newBut = "<input type='button' style='opacity:1;color:white; background-color:orange;' value='Enable'/>";
                $(newBut).prependTo($(theEle).closest("div")).click(function(e){
                    edit.setMode('design');
                    $(e.target).remove();
                    $(theEle).toggle();
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run the code below:

```
$("#tinymce").contentEditable="false";
```

if you have more than one editors, you can use their id like below

```
$("#tinymce[data-id='idOfTheEditor']").contentEditable="false";
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using tinymce-react 4.2.0 and managed to make my custom button always active by doing

```
editor.ui.registry.addButton('button', {
  text: 'My Fancy Button',
  onAction: () => alert('fancy button clicked'),
  onSetup: (api) => {
    const callback = () => {
      api.setEnabled(true);
    };
    editor.on('init', callback);
    return (api) => {
      editor.off('init', callback);
    };
  },
});
```

for build in buttons, I think the answer from 'Jérôme MEVEL' still valid.