# How to remove tinymce editor buttons from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE4.3.10 (as part of Wordpress 4.5.4). I create a custom tinymce editor using the code:

```
tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddEditor", false, captionId);

tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, captionId);
```

"captionId" points to a textarea. Editor works fine but I want to remove few buttons. How do I do that ? I am not using tinyMCE.init() -- mainly because I don't know if I should be using it and editors works anyway.

I can disable using:

```
tinyMCE.get(captionId).controlManager.setDisabled('bold', true);
```

but I want to remove it.

Also, `tinyMCE.get(captionId).controlManager.get('bold')` returns undefined.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `tinymce.init({})` to invoke the editor with specific settings.  If the ID of the `<textarea>` in question is contained in the variable `captionId` I would do this:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "#" + captionId,  //needs to be a string of the CSS selector for the ID
  .
  . 
  .
});
```

This will target only that `<textarea>` for initialization.  If you want to limit what options appear on the toolbar you can do so with the `toolbar` configuration option:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "#" + captionId,
  toolbar: [
    "table | insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic",
    "removeformat | fontsizeselect | forecolor backcolor"a11ycheck
  ],
  . 
  .
});
```

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#toolbar

Comment: Thank you so much!! Also I added "link" but not seeing the button for insert/edit link:                 toolbar: [
                    "undo redo bold italic link"
                ] ... Any idea ?

Comment: In order to use certain toolbar buttons or menu options you need to load some plugins.  https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/  For the `link` toolbar button to work you need to load the `link` plugin:  https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/link/

Comment: Thanks again! I was able to see the link button - however, the link modal window goes behind my current UI. I can call .focus() but dont have any handle on that window accessible in my code