# TinyMCE 5 - How to control which buttons are shown in toolbar?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

I have to remove some buttons from the tinyMCE 5 Editor.

[image]

How can I control which buttons are being shown?

I can't find anything in the [documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/full-featured/).

This is my init code:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea.property_remark'
    ,branding: true
    ,menubar: false
    ,statusbar: true
    ,toolbar: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it [here](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/basic-setup/#toolbarmenuconfiguration)

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea.property_remark'
    ,branding: true
    ,menubar: false
    ,statusbar: true
    ,toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | link image'
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to use certain toolbar buttons or menu options you need to load some plugins. check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41042061/how-to-remove-tinymce-editor-buttons-from-javascript)

Comment: link documentation [tinyMCE 5](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#toolbar)